# Insert into a view in Hive

Tags: view, hive

Can we insert into a view in Hive?
I have done this in the past with Oracle and Teradata. 
But, doesn't seem to work in Hive.

```
create table t2 (id int, key string, value string, ds string, hr string);

create view v2 as select id, key, value, ds, hr from t2;

insert into v2 values (1,'key1','value1','ds1','hr1')

***Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to determine if null is encrypted: java.lang.NullPointerException***
```

These seems to be some sort of update support in view. But, I can't see anything on insert into a view.
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/UpdatableViews

Thanks for the feedback. Makes sense. The reason behind needing this functionality is, we use an ETL tool that has problems with handling high precision decimals (>15 digits). If the object(table->column in this case) is represented as string within the tool, we don't have a problem. So, i thought i'll define a bunch of views with string datatypes and use that in the tool instead. But, can't do inserts in hive to view. So, may be i need to think of something else. Have done this way before with oracle and teradata.

Can we have two tables with different structures point to the same underlying hdfs content? Probably wouldn't work because fo the parquet storage which stores schema. Sorry, not a hadoop expert.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to insert data in a Hive view, Hive view is just a projection of a Hive table (you can see it as presaved query). From Hive documentation

> Note that a view is a purely logical object with **no associated
>   storage**. (No support for materialized views is currently available in
>   Hive.) When a query references a view, the view's definition is
>   evaluated in order to produce a set of rows for further processing by
>   the query. (This is a conceptual description; in fact, as part of
>   query optimization, Hive may combine the view's definition with the
>   query's, e.g. pushing filters from the query down into the view.)

Answer (score 1):

The link (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/UpdatableViews) seems to be for a proposed feature.

Per the [official documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Create/Drop/AlterView):

```
Views are read-only and may not be used as the target of LOAD/INSERT/ALTER.
```